# Deploying Laravel 5.7 in a folder in the root

Tags: deployment, laravel-5.7

**[UPDATE]**

When I use this code on the server it works but not on the localhost

```
{{ URL::asset('public/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}
```

---

I'm deploying Laravel project in a folder in the root so here's the .env

```
APP_URL=http://example.com/project
PUB_URL=/public
```

edited index.php file which is in the root

```
require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php';
//require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
//$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But all css and js files located in the public folder won't load I get log errors referring to the root path

```
GET http://example.com/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

These files are included in the blade like this

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

And htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews
     </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On

     # Redirect Trailing Slashes…
     RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

     # Handle Front Controller…
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How to fix this to fetch js, css file and images from the public directory inside the "project" folder not from the root domain?

Comment: just use asset('....')

Comment: the `APP_URL` var is only used for the CLI commands because there is no request being passed with the requested hostname defined ... and your site shouldn't be in a subfolder

Comment: @DiegoCespedes it works on the server but on the localhost it refers to the root of htdocs not to the project folder which makes it doesn't work how to make asset() work on localhost by referring to the project root inside localhost like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_project/public/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css instead of this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css